# I tried adding a simple play again feature to my guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to add a do you want to play again feature to my guessing game and it stopped working :( pls help. Im very new to python so i bet i have done many oblivious mistakes :S

```
import random

n = random.randint(1, 100)

play_game = input("Do you want to play ? Y/N :")
play_game = play_game.upper()
print("play_game")

while play_game == 'Y':
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
while n != "gissning":
    if guess < n:
        print("You guessed to low")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
    elif guess > n:
        print ("You guessed to high")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
    else:
        print("Gratz you guessed it")
        break
    
while play_game == 'Y':
    # your game 

    play_game = input("Do you want to play again? Y/N :").upper()
```

Comment: You don't need 3 individual loops, this way your program might stuck. Do it with only one loop, with an exit condition of the player don't want to play again. Guessing could be another loop of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are a few little problems in your code, but with a bit of logic you can figure it out.

First, you don't want three separated `while` loops, since when you quit one you'll never reach it again unless you restart your code. You actually want *nested loops*. The outer one will verify if the user wants to play again, while the inner one will keep asking guesses until it matches the random number.

And second, you want to compare `n`, the random number, to `guess`, the user's input. In your code you're comparing `n != "gissning"`, which will never be true since `n` is a number and `"gissning"`, a string.

With that in mind you can change your code a little bit and have something like:

```
import random

print("play_game")
play_game = input("Do you want to play ? Y/N :").upper()
highscore = 0

while play_game == 'Y':
    n = random.randint(1, 100)
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
    score = 1
    while n != guess:
        if guess < n:
            print("You guessed to low")
        elif guess > n:
            print("You guessed to high")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Gratz you guessed it")
        highscore = score if score < highscore or highscore == 0 else highscore
        print('Your score this turn was', score)
        print('Your highscore is', highscore)
        play_game = input("Do you want to play again? Y/N :").upper()
```

Hope this helps you out. Good luck in your Python journey! Let us know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Hey bro you helped me out a lot, i would be forever thankful if you also could show me how to add a highscore feature that updates :)

Comment: Haha you're welcome, buddy. What do you mean by a "highscore feature" ? You'd like to show your current user's score that's updated every time he/she guesses the right number?

Comment: Like if i guess the number in 6 tries on the first round then the highscore will be 6. But if i guess the number on round two in 4 tries then the highscore will update to 4.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. See if that is what you wanted

Comment: Your a bloody wizard making it look so simple thank you so much. Any tips for me to improve? When i see code i understand it but i have a hard time making my own. Sorry for many questions ;P

Comment: Hahaha the first thing you already have: motivation. Then you just need to practice. I've been learning by myself through videos, articles and many, MANY exercises. Python is an excellent first programming language since it has a lot of stuff on the internet, so keep on! The real secret is to never be shy. Try to do different projects and to improve the ones you liked the most. The sky is your roof, let your curiosity take you deep into the multiple possibilities. And, of course, we'll be always happy to help you if you need. Good luck! Hope you'll be soon answering my questions over here :D

Answer (score 0):

The next input prompt should be inside the outer-while loop. You also need to print the "Gratz you guessed it" along with the prompt and outside the inner-while loop when it's already n == guess.

```
import random

play_game = input("Do you want to play ? Y/N :")
play_game = play_game.upper()

while play_game == 'Y':
  print("play_game")
  n = random.randint(1, 100)

  guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
  while n != guess:
    if guess < n:
        print("You guessed to low")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))
    elif guess > n:
        print ("You guessed to high")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 och 100: "))

  print("Gratz you guessed it")

  play_game = input("Do you want to play ? Y/N :")
  play_game = play_game.upper()
```